# Day view, how to make custom event card / event content?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

In a day view, how to change style of the event content.

I am able to make custom toolbar and change some styling for timeSlotWrapper but not able to take control of event content.

I have tried below code and achieved some customization using below code.
I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rbc-eventcard-hzg6y) with all the code I have so far.

Currently I have this:

[image]

Expected -

[image]

I want to be able to show those colored bars with event content.

I tried searching in [issues](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues) but could not find any code that can help me so far.

Could someone pls help point me to right direction?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom event layout and pass it into your [components](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-components) prop

```
<Calendar
  components={{
    event: CustomEvent
  }}
  ...other props
/>
```

you can also use the [eventPropGetter](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-eventPropGetter) prop for adding in additional classnames or styles.